# Using sensors as an invisible barrier to doorway

Tags: sensor

Recently I had a pet escape my apartment out the front door without anyone noticing. I was looking for a way to avoid this again by putting some kind of tracker in a collar and a sensor in a door way that will send a notification via ifttt to my phone or to my echo dot. I'm assuming I could do the notification with a raspberry pi but I have no idea what sensor or tracker I'd need for this. Any ideas here?

Comment: maybe bluetooth low energy.

Comment: The notification will be sent every time the pet approaches the front door. What is the height of the collar from the ground?

Comment: @Jasen for the sensors? Im not sure what kind of sensor would interact with Bluetooth in that manner. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Umar the collar would be 1ft -1.5ft off the ground

Comment: i can think of IR/PIR sensor with two installations to detect the motion, near the front door. One at a level, where only pets will reach(2 ft or less) and another to suppress the signal when humans enter/exit (3 feet or higher). This will not call for any collars for the pet. A hardware with out MCU or a simple arduino would analyse the data and buzz. Also, care for a GPS tracker for pet, if the one is escaping a lot :) + weight monitor on the mat (<20kg, warning :))

Comment: RFID tag could help, plus its receiver in out going door.

Comment: bluetooth is built in to raspberry pi 3 or you can get one on USB and use a cable to put it nearer the door.

Comment: @Umar can you go into what you would use for the IR/PIr sensors? I'm not sure how I'd use them in the way you're talking about but this with an Arduino sounds very interesting.

Comment: Motion sensor: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13285IR sensor https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8958. two sensors are needed, Either motion sensor or IR sensor. One at 1 feet from ground and another at 3 feet from ground. If both, triggers, it is a human motion, ignore. If only bottom one gets sensed, probably pet. check out.

Comment: @Umar so I would use a raspberry pi to handle the logic for these?

Comment: a cheaper Arduino pro mini is sufficient if you are using external GSM modem for SMS alerts. If you just need a signal (Ex.: buzzer), then pro mini alone is sufficient. It can also be done without any boards, using a few transistors too. But i would suggest to go for programmable boards as some logics can be added (Time of the day, manual sensor disable, whether door is closed etc.)

Comment: There are packaged consumer products for that.  Most of them are intended to work in yards, but could easily be hacked to work in buildings.

Comment: @Harper What products are you referring to?

Comment: @Umar I will look into the sensors you sent along with the arduino pro mini. Are these pretty simple to setup?

Comment: @saboehnke We're not a product reco site... *looks left looks right, coast is clear* https://www.thepawtracker.com/blogs/the-pet-tracker-blog-by-the-paw-tracker/84621315-top-13-gps-pet-trackers-dog-and-cat-cell-phones-best-of-2016-reviewed

Comment: Yes. They are simple to set up

Comment: @Harper Those seem to be a bit pricey if I don't want a monthly subscription (which I don't). Those are interesting though. Just wish there was one that I could setup a safe zone and not have to worry about a monthly payment or hundreds of dollars up front.

Comment: I was also thinking of invisible fence, where an antenna in the dog's collar detects proximity to a wire, but unfortunately this *shocks the dog* rather than use telecomms to notify the user.   On the upside, this keeps the dog within WiFi range, so perhaps one could be hacked, replacing the shock unit with comms.